# Best Ruby on Rails Front-end development strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, workflow, frontend

Hey all you ruby on railers...

I'm just a newbie as of right now.. currently work on my first rails project at work.

I'm going to be taking some time on my own time to dig deeper and I was wondering what the best strategy is to go about front-end development of a rails app.

is it better/easier to have a workflow like the following

```
1. Concept / Idea
2. Wireframe, Mockup
3. *** Design front-end of the app
4. Rails development
5. template all the views
```

or is it better to do it flipped?

```
1. Concept / Idea
2. Wireframe, Mockup
3. Rails development
4. Template all the views
5. *** Design front-end of the app
```

Maybe neither of these?

How do you go about your ruby on rails workflow.
I'm a complete mashup of developer / designer

But most of my inspiration comes from having an idea, then designing designing it, then doing all the front-end

What are some thoughts ideas for better rails workflows when you know exactly what you want the front-end of the site to look like.

Comment: This is either off-topic, or not constructive. This is about the process of software development, not a specific programming problem. It's also not at all specific to Rails. This may be better on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can work either way. Different companies -- or even different projects in the same company -- can reach success with different approaches.

That being said, I have a pretty strong preference for the following approach:

1. Concept / Idea
2. Wireframe, Mockup
3. Design front-end of the app
4. Template all the views
5. Rails Development

Basically, I usually describe it this way:

- First, do the design to the point of having mockups and images laid out by a designer.
- Have a UI specialist convert that to HTML/CSS (or HAML/SASS or whatever)
- Do the rails implementation behind the html.

These steps will normally overlap -- and that's OK. You should start some basic development prior to getting everything eles final. But the more you have the design done ahead of time the better.

Note that this approach doesn't mean design the entire site in detail before anything else is done. It means that once you've decided to do some coding, do the design for that bit first. You'll want to implement things in small chunks and iterate as you do the development. Implement things in small chunks, but try to get the design for those pieces done before you start coding.